# CV Formatting Problems: Picture, Date, Page Number and References

Tags: fonts, graphics, classicthesis, letters, cv

I desperately need help. I'm currently starting out with LaTeX, and I absolutely love it, it's gorgeous. I tried a template for my CV, it's very good.
Here's the Code:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar  

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} 

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 
\vspace{0.5em}} 

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} 

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} 

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987}

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} 

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} 

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} 

\vspace{1em} 

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} 

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern, \textsc{Initech Inc}  --- Chicago}

\Description{\MarginText{Initech Inc}Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork. \\
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Reference: Bill \textsc{Lumbergh}&\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:bill@initech.com}{bill@initech.com}}\\
Reference: Thomas \textsc{Norough}&\ \ +1 (000) 444 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:thomas@initech.com}{thomas@initech.com}}\\
\end{tabular}
%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{Jan-Mar 2011}{Computer Technician, \textsc{Buy More} --- Burbank}

\Description{\MarginText{Buy More}Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again. \\
Reference: Big \textsc{Mike}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:mike@buymore.com}{mike@buymore.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2011-2012}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Masters of Commerce}GPA: 8.0\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \textit{First Class Honours}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: Business and Administration\newline 
Thesis: \textit{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}\newline
Description: This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.\newline
Advisors: Prof.~James \textsc{Smith} \& Assoc. Prof.~Jane \textsc{Smith}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2007-2010}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Bachelor of Business Studies}GPA: 7.5\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \textit{Commerce Specialization}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: Business and Administration\newline
Description: This degree focussed heavily on important things such as personnel management and mundane paperwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Computer Skills}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Basic}\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}

\Description{\MarginText{Intermediate}\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}

\Description{\MarginText{Advanced}Computer Hardware and Support}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTHER INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Other Information}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Awards}2011\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{2010\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Communication Skills}2010\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}

\vspace{-0.5em}

\Description{2009\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em}

\newlength{\langbox} 
\settowidth{\langbox}{English} 

\Description{\MarginText{Languages}\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{English}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Mothertongue}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Spanish}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Intermediate (conversationally fluent)}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Dutch}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Basic (simple words and phrases only)}

\vspace{1em}

%------------------------------------------------

\Description{\MarginText{Interests}Piano\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Cooking\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Running\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Chess\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Dancing}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs completely, and I would like to change up a few things:

1. I want to move the first section (Personal Information) to the left, so I can put my Photo on the right side of it, symmetrically of course.
2. Picture: As stated in 1), I would like to add my photo to the upper right
3. Unfortunately, I'm German, and the date is in English. It says: "May 2, 2016", but in German it needs to be "2. Mai 2016".
4. Additionally I would like to have my Name directly over the date, and a little space atop, to digitally sign above it.
5. On the second page, there is a page number appearing, I would like to know, why its so far up, and if there is a way to move it, possibly even having a second digit for total pages, like this: "1 of 2".
6. Lastly, I would like the names, dots, e-mail-adresses and phone numbers to line up vertically throughout the document, and if there are more than one references for one work position, I would like to have the second reference directly under it, without having the "Reference:" before it, in the second row. Additionally, those references (including the other data like phone an email) should line up. vertically with every other reference in the document.

This is actually pretty urgent, because there's a deadline.

I googled everything I can think of, but unsuccessfully.

I hope you guys can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get this template?

Comment: IMHO starting from scratch with `moderncv` ([see examples here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples)) might be the easier task than dissecting an overly complex template and re-engineering it for your purpose (see [Markus Kohm's "Minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme"](http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage) (in German)).

Comment: `classicthesis` causes many problems -- just don't use it.

Comment: That's an awful lot of dtp type work in one question.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Most likely latex-templlates.com

Comment: @hakaze I can understand a user who is not using `moderncv`. I find it extremely ugly and overused.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fully agreed, `classicthesis` is bad.

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, six questions in one doesn't fit the format of the site.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger There you go! http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go... I figured you could figure how to plop the graphic element up top.

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------        ----------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar  

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 

\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} 

\newcommand{\NeuEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0%     
\parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3% 
\vspace{0.5em}} % Made a new control sequence called \NeuEntry

\newcommand{\PersEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0%
\hskip-1.5in\parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3% 
\vspace{0.5em}} % Made a new control sequence called \PersEntry notice%
                % it is \hskip-1.5in so that brings it Left

\newcommand{\Description}[1]%      
{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright%
\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} 


%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------

\begin{document}

\clearscrheadfoot% Cleared the scrartcl header and footer

 \cfoot{\vskip-.8in\thepage\ of 2}% Did the footer in `page of 2` format
                                  % and negative \vskip to bring it                           
                                  % upwards

\pagestyle{scrheadings}% using scrheadings page style

%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} 

\hskip-.8cm\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}%
\vspace{0.5em} 

\def\NewEntry{\PersEntry}% Defined \NewEntry as \PersEntry so I wouldn't
                         % have to change each \NewEntry by hand

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{2. Mai 2016}

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} 

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}}   


\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112}%

\vspace{1em} 

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} 

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}%
\vspace{2em} 

%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\def\NewEntry{\NeuEntry}% Defined \NewEntry as \NeuEntry which%
                        %  has the original \NewEntry parameters

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst,%
 \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}%
Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a%
 wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals),%
 managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes,%
 liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.\\%    
Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \%
     $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern, \textsc{Initech Inc} --- Chicago}

\Description{\MarginText{Initech Inc}% 
Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.\\%
 %%Here I made a \vtop box so Bill and Thomas would line up%%
References:\vtop{ Bill \textsc{Lumbergh}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \%     
$\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:bill@initech.com}{bill@initech.com}\\%
Thomas \textsc{Norough}\ \ +1 (000) 444 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \%     
\href{mailto:thomas@initech.com}{thomas@initech.com}}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{Jan-Mar 2011}{Computer Technician,%
 \textsc{Buy More}---Burbank}

\Description{\MarginText{Buy More}Worked in the Nerd Herd%
 and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers%
 to turn their computers off and on again. \\%
 Reference: Big \textsc{Mike}\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \%     
\href{mailto:mike@buymore.com}{mike@buymore.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2011-2012}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Masters of Commerce}%
GPA: 8.0\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ %    
\textit{First Class Honours}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School: Business and%     
Administration\newline 
Thesis: \textit{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}\newline%
Description: This thesis explored the idea that money has been%
the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world.%
I found that it has, in fact, not.\newline%
Advisors: Prof.~James \textsc{Smith} \& Assoc. Prof.~Jane \textsc{Smith}}

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2007-2010}{The University of California, Berkeley}

\Description{\MarginText{Bachelor of Business Studies}GPA: 7.5\ \%
 $\cdotp$\ \ \textit{Commerce Specialization}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School:% 
Business and Administration\newline%
Description: This degree focussed heavily on important things%
 such as personnel management and mundane paperwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS
%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Computer Skills}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Basic}\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}

\Description{\MarginText{Intermediate}%
\textsc{python}, \textsc{html},%
\LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}

\Description{\MarginText{Advanced}Computer Hardware and Support}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} 

%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------
%   OTHER INFORMATION
%------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Other Information}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Awards}2011\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ School of Business%
 Postgraduate Scholarship}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{2010\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\date{\empty}% This had to be empty, or a very unattractive date%
             % inexplicably appeared at the end

\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Communication Skills}2010%
\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}

\vspace{-0.5em}

\Description{2009\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ %
Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em}

\newlength{\langbox} 
\settowidth{\langbox}{English} 

\Description{\MarginText{Languages}\parbox{\langbox}%
{\textsc{English}}\ \     $\cdotp$\ \ \ Mothertongue}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Spanish}}%
\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \  Intermediate (conversationally fluent)}

\vspace{-0.5em} 

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Dutch}%
}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Basic     (simple words and phrases only)}

\vspace{1em}

%------------------------------------------------

\Description{\MarginText{Interests}Piano%
\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Cooking\ \     $\cdotp$\ \ Running%
\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Chess\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Dancing}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are very welcome.  If the answer is what you needed, usually it can be marked as "the answer" by selecting it.

Comment: And usually, that's all the thanks that is needed :) You should also feel free to vote for the post yourself.